# Replay actions React-Router-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm having issues replaying location change actions in Redux DevTools. I'm pretty new to Redux and I'm trying to make a full Redux app using latest packages react-redux 5.0.4, react-router 4.1.1, react-router-redux 5.0.0-alpha.4

After lots of struggles, the store is passed down from Provider using connect and the router is connected properly with ConnectedRouter (followed official [doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux)), route changing works, actions appear on Redux DevTools, but if I replay them, the location remains the same (last location won't change), so if you transition from /login/test to /forgot-password and press replay, the screen won't render the /login/test and then change, it will just stay at /forgot-password.

Attached both code and Redux DevTools state export. If anyone has the slightest idea of the cause, please let me know, thanks in advance!

```js
import React from 'react';
import CompLogin from '/client/Components/User/Login/login.jsx';

import { routerActions, push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.testChange = this.testChange.bind(this); 
    }

    testChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.goToPath('/forgot-password');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="homepage">
                <p onClick={this.testChange}>here</p>
                <CompLogin match={this.props.match}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        goToPath: (location) => {
          dispatch(routerActions.push(location));
        }
    }
}


Login = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);

export default Login;
```

```js
{
 "payload": "[{\"type\":\"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE\",\"payload\":{\"pathname\":\"/login/dsa\",\"search\":\"\",\"hash\":\"\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\"},\"payload\":{\"name\":\"emailAddress\",\"type\":\"Field\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\"},\"payload\":{\"name\":\"password\",\"type\":\"Field\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/FOCUS\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"emailAddress\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/CHANGE\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"emailAddress\",\"touch\":false,\"persistentSubmitErrors\":false},\"payload\":\"d\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/CHANGE\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"emailAddress\",\"touch\":false,\"persistentSubmitErrors\":false},\"payload\":\"ds\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/CHANGE\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"emailAddress\",\"touch\":false,\"persistentSubmitErrors\":false},\"payload\":\"dsa\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/BLUR\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"emailAddress\",\"touch\":true},\"payload\":\"dsa\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/FOCUS\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"password\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/CHANGE\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"password\",\"touch\":false,\"persistentSubmitErrors\":false},\"payload\":\"d\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/CHANGE\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"password\",\"touch\":false,\"persistentSubmitErrors\":false},\"payload\":\"ds\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/CHANGE\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"password\",\"touch\":false,\"persistentSubmitErrors\":false},\"payload\":\"dsa\"},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/BLUR\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompLogin\",\"field\":\"password\",\"touch\":true},\"payload\":\"dsa\"},{\"type\":\"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE\",\"payload\":{\"pathname\":\"/forgot-password\",\"search\":\"\",\"hash\":\"\",\"key\":\"26xvm2\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/DESTROY\",\"meta\":{\"form\":[\"CompLogin\"]}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompForgotPassword\"},\"payload\":{\"name\":\"emailAddress\",\"type\":\"Field\"}},{\"type\":\"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE\",\"payload\":{\"pathname\":\"/forgot-password\",\"search\":\"\",\"hash\":\"\",\"key\":\"3jad4s\"}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/DESTROY\",\"meta\":{\"form\":[\"CompLogin\"]}},{\"type\":\"@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD\",\"meta\":{\"form\":\"CompForgotPassword\"},\"payload\":{\"name\":\"emailAddress\",\"type\":\"Field\"}}]"
}
```

Comment: Can you use `this.props.history.push('/forgot-password');`?

Comment: @Chris Yes, works just like this.props.goToPath, replay doesn't work. (logs in Redux Dev Tools, changes route, everything fine, only when I press replay, I don't get to the /login/test screen, it just stays on /forgot-password).